# Mac Pro 5,1 - Red LED's On Slot #4 and Slot #8 - No Processor Error

Tags: memory, mac-pro

I have a Mac Pro 5,1 dual processor. When powered on, no matter what slot the RAM is in, I get a light on slot #4 and one on slot #8 even though those slots are empty. No processor warning lights at all.

I haven't encountered this before. I've tried different RAM in different slots, SMC reset and swapping the processor board out for a spare. No joy. Such a state doesn't appear to be detailed in the service source manual for the machine.

Edit: The machine won't boot - so AHT isn't possible.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware fault, have you run Apple Hardware Test: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201257

Comment: @unknowndomain I didn't mention it in the post, I should have, but the machine won't boot, so AHT isn't possible.

Comment: Have you reseated the CPU riser card?

Comment: Out of left-field... have you changed the PRAM battery yet? I've had some real weirdness if the battery was failing, inc random RAM issues & no-boot.

Comment: @Tetsujin good thought. I'll try that - although I'm beginning to suspect there might be a firmware mismatch between the board and the tray.

Comment: @unknowndomain yes - an blown it out with a pc vac - no joy

Comment: Sounds like you need to get it repaired then.